# Swtich off iphone only after putting the passcode

Tags: ios7

Is it possible to reassign a different task to the power button? I am asking this so that if the iphone gets lost the thief can easily switch it off even though it is locked.By re assigning the power button nobody will be able to switch off the phone with out knowing the pass key. For a smart phone this should be the basic feature to unlock the phone using the passcode and then switching it off. I guess most of the other smart phones require  the passcode even to switch them off

Comment: Most other smartphones can have their battery removed...

Comment: Send your feedback to apple support team.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. If you really wanted to though, I'm sure you could on a jailbroken device and code which would never make it into the App Store. Imagine a bunch of apps redefining how the home button works so you can't leave the app easily and have to puzzle out how to background the app (or make it impossible to leave the app). Hardly something Apple would allow.

Even were it possible, it would be a royal nuisance to the user. Passcode to unlock, read text message, passcode to lock again. For what... security which could be easily bypassed?

Even assuming you can't remove the battery, pop out the SIM card or deaden the wireless signal there is the low level power off switch which is designed to work even if the whole device is frozen up. The whole point of being about to force turn off/reboot is to always work no matter what. So all the effort could be bypassing in 10 seconds.